# sql regexp in hebrew

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, hebrew

I try to build Regexp in for sql (in this case MySql), that will find all string without a specific patter, the pattern is [four Hebrew laters] - [Hebrew letters with white spaces] - [Hebrew letters with white spaces] - [digits].

I try this one:

```
select ('תשעה-מורי מורים פדגוגיה איכותית מקוון-אשקלון-1096'  NOT REGEXP '^[\u05D0-\u05EA]{4}[\s]?\-[\s]?[\u05D0-\u05EA\s]{1,}[\s]?\-[\s]?[\u05D0-\u05EA\s]{1,}[\s]?\-[\s]?[0-9]{1,}$');
```

more example of not match inputs:

```
'3232-בדיקה-ד'
'בדיקה בדיקה-אילת-123'
```

Match input are

```
'תשעה-בדיקה בדיקה-אשקלון-1111' 
'תשעו-בדיקה נוספת-בת ים-12341'
```

In addtiton I can't use `[[:number:]]` because the application running the sql use `:` as parameter

this one return always 1 but I expected to get 0;

Any Idea?

Comment: `four Hebrew laters` -  You meant *letters*? Could you provide input matching & not matching your need?

Comment: Yes I meant to letters, not match is '3232-בדיקה-ד' or 'בדיקה בדיקה-אילת-123'
Match input are 'תשעה-בדיקה בדיקה-אשקלון-1111' or  'תשעו-בדיקה נוספת-בת ים-12341'
In addtiton I can't use [[:number:]] because the application running the sql use ":"  as parameter

Comment: Please, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33541420/edit) with the examples. Could you provide more?

Comment: Your second item doesn't match, it has 5 numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is the regexp that work for me 
'^[א-ת]{4}-[א-ת" "0-9a-zA-Z)(,`:]+-[א-ת" "]+-[0-9]+$'
Thanks Thomas for your quicke response

Answer (score 1):

Note that character classes do not work for MySQL's `REGEXP`, except by coincidence.  Only byte compares work, not 2-byte Hebrew utf8 characters.

Another approach uses HEX.

- Digits are all 1-byte hex `3x`
- Hebrew (at least the common characters) are all 2-byte hex `D7xx`
- space is hex `20`
- dash is hex `2D`

Those are not quite perfect -- there are characters other than Digits and Hebrew in the hex I gave.

So, "[four Hebrew laters] - [Hebrew letters with white spaces] - [Hebrew letters with white spaces] - [digits]" is

```
HEX(col) REGEXP '^(D7..){4}-(D7..|20)+-(D7..|20)+-(3.)+$'
```

That assumes `col` is just the pattern.  If you are searching for the pattern inside `col`:

```
HEX(col) REGEXP '(..)*(D7..){4}-(D7..|20)+-(D7..|20)+-(3.)+'
```

The `(..)*` says any number of hex digit pairs`.  (OK, overkill, but faster.)

Comment: Significant changes happened with MySQL 8.0.